# How can I input a text file using a command line argument and convert it into a string?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to reference a file through using it as a command line argument, assuming the file is in the same directory. I then need to convert the first argument into a string. Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "header.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
string arg1 = argv[1];
string arg2 = argv[2];
string fLine;
ifstream input(arg1);

if (input.is_open()) {
    while ( getline (input, fLine)) {
        cout << fLine << endl;
    }
input.close();
}
return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine but when I try execute it the error is

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: And what is the required second parameter to your program that you're passing, on the command line, when you execute it (in ***addition*** to the first parameter, the filename to read)?

Comment: A file to output to later in the program. Havent gotten up to it yet though

Comment: Please extend your MRE with detailed info on how exactly you call it, especially what the command line arguments are.

Comment: What do you mean "a file to output to later". Command line parameters are text strings, not files. Again, what are you passing, exactly as the 2nd parameter when you execute this program. Just because you "havent gotten to it" doesn't mean that the 2nd mandatory parameter, that your `main()` expects to exist, can be ignored.

Comment: sorry, I've removed the argv[2] from the program, I'm trying to pass a string that should match up with the name of a text file, text.txt, I then want to read the text file and input the contents of it into a string

Comment: so for example ./program text.txt

Answer (score 0):

In C++ array indices start with 0.

So, argv[0] will be the path/name of your program and argv[1] will be the name of the file that you want to work with.

argv[2] does most probably not exist. Will be nullptr and hence the error message.

You should always check argc, to see, how many arguments have been passed. But beware. argv[0] is always the name/path of your program.

EDIT: Please try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "header.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    string arg1 = argv[1];
    string fLine;
    ifstream input(arg1);

    if (input) {
        while (getline(input, fLine)) {
            cout << fLine << endl;
        }
        input.close();
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error: cannot open " << arg1 << '\n';
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looking at the question I do not see the relevance of discussing the ignored argv[0] and argv[2]. The discussion of wether argc[1] is NULL seems to be the core, but you treat it more or less as a side issue.

Comment: Yes, and I need to use argv[1] as the text file to read from, this is assuming the argument is the same as the name of the text file

Comment: @Hidden456: Please see my edit and try the attached modification.

Answer (score 0):

From the [constructor documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) for `std::string`:

> `from c-string (4)     string (const char* s);`

> If s is a null pointer, if n == npos, or if the range specified by [first,last) is not valid, it causes undefined behavior.

Your implementation is choosing to throw an exception here when passed a `nullptr` value for `const char* s`.

As noted above, it is likely that `string arg2 = argv[2];` is generating this error (and it is possible that accessing `argv[2]` itself is undefined, as you only mention a single argument being provided to the program.

Comment: The value of arg1 is the name of the argument, though, I've verified that. I've also removed the arg2 initialisation for now.